# What's the difference between rendering a status code and using head?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, status, head

In a tutorial, I've seen both used. Besides the fact that it seems better to use `head` for a delete request, what are the real reasons between this and `render status: 200`?

Other examples:

1. `render json: user, status: 200, location: [:api, user]`
2. `head 204`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

head returns no body in the response. It's an http response with specific code that's it.
If you expect for example a json response (as in the above example, you serialise the user object to a json), this will not work for you.

If all you need is good/bad, head is perfect and is very light weight. if for example you want to actually return a created/deleted object (just as an example) you should use render.